# navigation bar in Detail side of master-detail controller missing

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, storyboard, master-detail

I made masterdetailview with different `viewcontrollers` in my `storyboard` and linked every one with push `segue`. Now when I click on list item new `DetailViewController` opens, but every single one have no `navigationbar`. I added `navigation item` on top off every View, added title for every single one, but after all that `navigation bar` is not showing. I am working on `iPad` app and in both orientations navigation bar is missing.

**EDIT:**

My appDelegate is same as template when you create your Master-Detail project:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
        splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

One of my DetailViewControllers:

```
#import "MediaExpDetailViewController.h"

@interface MediaExpDetailViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *masterPopoverController;
@end

@implementation MediaExpDetailViewController

#pragma mark - Managing the detail item

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;
    }
    if (self.masterPopoverController != nil) {
        [self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
}


- (void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

#pragma mark - Split view

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    barButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"MasterButton", @"Master");
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
    self.masterPopoverController = popoverController;
}

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
{
    // Called when the view is shown again in the split view, invalidating the button and popover controller.
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
    self.masterPopoverController = nil;
}


@end
```

Comment: can you add you code how you have done at AppDelegate and one of your controller

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your DetailViewController has to be connected to a UINavigationController. If you set up a new master-detail-project from Xcode's "New Project" menu you will get this:

[image]

**Notice:** Every Detail view controller has to be connected to a UINavigationController (directly or indirectly).

**Edit:** To connect multiple UINavigationControllers, do the following:
Your initial detail views UINavigationController is connected with the split view (as usual). Every others detail views UINavigationController is connected with the master view (with a *replace segue*):

[image]

If you want to give the user the possibility to switch back to the initial detail view, you also have to connect the initial view controller with the master (thus having two connections, one to the split, one to the master).

To switch between detail view controllers, you call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` in your master view controller.

**Edit 2:**

To add your detail views as the split view's delegate implement the following method, which gets called earlier than `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.splitViewController.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: I have connected every Detail View with my Navigation controller see this [link](http://oi40.tinypic.com/25j82df.jpg)

Comment: Which of these detail views has the UINavigationController as **root view controller**? If the answer is *none*, then there may be your problem. Add a UINavigationController to each DetailViewController and connect it as **root view controller**

Comment: root view controller is view controller with a picture in it, other view controllers are linked via push segue. Only root view controller have navigation bar visible.

Comment: That is exactly what I said.. every view controller has to have a navigation controller as its root. In your case only one has root, therefore only one has a navigation bar. You have to create 9 more UINavigationControllers.

Comment: If I set FirstDetailViewController to be root view controller, and than try to set SecondDetailViewController to be root, first segue connection is detached! **there can be only one root view controller at the time**

Comment: I know! Did you read my post? If you want 10 different detail view controllers, you have to have 10 different navigation controllers.

Comment: Sorry I read it but didn't quite understand it at first. So when I create 2 navigation controllers, I tried to connect second one to a split view controller as a detail view controller, but then I lost connection with first navigation controller and split view controller. How can I connect multiple navigation controllers?

Comment: Now I get error: **'Receiver (<MasterViewController: 0x8171390>) has no segue with identifier 'MediaExpDetailViewController''**. I have connected split view controller with navigation controller with segue named MediaExpDetailViewController and I call [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MediaExpDetailViewController" sender:self];

Comment: The relationship between your **initial** detail view and your split view is (of course) a relationship segue and not a manual segue (choose **detail view controller** as relationship). All **manual segues** (like push or **replace**) go from **master** to **navigation**.

Comment: I am struggling with this problem for several hours and couldn't find answer. When i am in portrait and launch app, press bar button and choose item from list, bar button is missing. When I go to land->portrait again button appear. I assigned delegate to detail view in viewDidLoad and I am sure that this is the problem, but don't know how to properly assign delegate.

Comment: I am still missing button when I am using only portrait, swipe is working. Now when I change orientation to land app crashes. No info about crash.

Comment: @lugonja hello, how did you solve this problem as I am facing the same issue right now